# Use Touchscreen and MF-RC522 via SPI simultaneously

Tags: display, spi, nfc

So recently I've been testing the official 7" touchscreen and everything went ok. But after adding the last update of the bcm2835 library to use the SPI port in order to use the MF-RC522 board, the touch interface stopped working.

So, what could this be due to? I need to use both of them at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Comment: I think what you mean is you can't figure out how to use both of them at the same time, not that installing libbcm2835 caused the screen to stop working.

Comment: That could be the problem, yes. How can I manage to use both of them at the same time?

Comment: Have a look [at this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/add-more-than-2-spi-slaves) but I suspect the touchscreen driver hogs the bus so you are out of luck.  I could be wrong.

Comment: But if the touchscreen hogs the SPI bus it will still be working. It should be the RC522 board the one which wouldn't work, don't you think? Is there any way I could check the SPI bus traffic?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use the SPI bus, but it sounds like you are homing in further on what your real question is.  My first comment was simply to point out that if simply *installing* libbcm2835 has disabled the touchscreen even when the other board is not in use or attached, you've made some other mistake/done some additional thing at some point.  Installing the library could not, all by itself, disable the SPI bus, etc.

Comment: Put another way, labelling a question *Raspberry Pi 7" Touchscreen not working*, then implying (even if it is just sematic confusion) that it is because you installed libbcm2835 probably will **not** get the attention of the people who can help you, because you aren't asking the right question -- perhaps you are assuming everybody just reads everything all the way through because these are problems other people must solve (false).  Hence, making an effort to be as *clear* and **precise** as you can will be of benefit to you.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I just didn't know how to ask the question in a better way. Thanks @goldilocks

Comment: I've changed your title to something more precise ;)  A big reason I see an issue here is we probably get a question or two a week from people who bought a touchscreen and it doesn't work.  Most of them end up being  because of driver or connection issues (or just plain get ignored).  Your question is very different from those.

Comment: Are you using different SPI channels?  Did the code you are using ever work?  Where is the code?

Comment: The touchscreen I don´t even know the channel which is using. Fot the NFC module I'm using [this](https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python) library with the SPI_CE0 pin attached to the module.

The code is the Read.py example from the lib.

Comment: They can't use the same chip select.  Have you tried using SPI_CE1 for your NFC module instead?

Comment: Nope. I've just realised about that, tomorrow I will give it a try. Thanks man!

Comment: That didn't work as expected, even if I disconnect the MFRC522 module, the touchscreen doesn't work anymore.