# How to use RC522 RFID on spidev1.x on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, pi-3, spi, rfid

I followed this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56513/57412 trying to use my RC522 on spi 1.0 but I'm stuck.

Could someone give me a hand wiring correctly (I hope it is) and how to use the right Python library and codes in order to get it working.

I use RPi3.

I added this to `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=spi1-3cs
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

and if I search, I can see this:

```
ls /dev/spi*
/dev/spidev0.0  /dev/spidev0.1  /dev/spidev1.0  /dev/spidev1.1   /dev/spidev1.2
```

I used these repos:

```
https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python 
https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py
```

and here is the wiring list:

```
Name    Pin #   Pin name
SDA     36      BCM16
SCK     40      BCM21
MOSI    38      BCM20
MISO    35      BCM19
IRQ     None    None
GND     Any     Any Ground
RST     None    None
3.3V    1       3V3
```

How can I find where the RC522 is actually connected? On which spidev?

Answer (score 1):

Use this **repository:** https://github.com/ondryaso/pi-rc522

It implements **IRQ** (Interruption Request) that makes insignificant CPU usage and much more efficient the reading process **(non-blocking)**. You will need to add one more cable from the IRQ pin on the MFRC522.

Answer (score 0):

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html#Type_3 shows the needed SPI GPIO.

For the auxiliary SPI (spidev1.x) you need to connect miso, mosi, sclk.

You also need to choose a slave select line as follows.  It doesn't matter which you use.

```
ce0  for spidev1.0
ce1  for spidev1.1
ce2  for spidev1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I actualy get it working with my previous settings here in my first post. However I think it's because i used an older version according to my "uname -a":

```
Linux raspberry 4.4.13-v7+ #894 SMP Mon Jun 13 13:13:27 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

So i think that the problem could come with my tests under the last Pixel desktop release.

I could mark this post as closed if anyone could confirm my opinion on pixel or not ...